# Accessing struct variable outside of {{range .}} scope in golang html template

Tags: html, templates, go

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Test </title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h2>Reply</h2>
        <form action="/post/{{$threadID}}" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="subject" />
        <input type="text" name="name" value="Anonymous" />
        <input type="text" name="message" />
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <div>
        {{range .}}
        {{$threadID := .ThreadID}}
        <h3>{{.Subject}}</h3>
        <h3>{{.Name}}</h3>
        <div>{{.DatePosted}}</div>
        <div><p>{{.Text}}</p></div>
        <br /><br />
        {{end}}
    </div>
</body>
```

I have this template, there is a form at the top of the page that requires the threadID from ANY one of the Posts sent (they're all the same, a slice of all posts with a certain threadID), this obviously doesn't work, my only other idea was something along the lines of

```
{{range .}}
    {{if $threadID == nil}}
        $threadID := .ThreadID
        //build the form same as above
    {{end}}
    <h3>{{.Subject}}</h3>
    <h3>{{.Name}}</h3>
    <div>{{.DatePosted}}</div>
    <div><p>{{.Text}}</p></div>
    <br /><br />
{{end}}
```

Here is the Post structure and methods if any of the above is unclear.

```
type Post struct {
threadID int
subject string
name string
text string
date_posted string
}

func (p *Post) ThreadID()   int    { return p.threadID    }
func (p *Post) Subject()    string { return p.subject     }
func (p *Post) Name()       string { return p.name        }
func (p *Post) Text()       string { return p.text        }
func (p *Post) DatePosted() string { return p.date_posted }
```

And the origin of the slice of posts sent to the template

```
threadID := r.URL.Path[len("/reply/"):]
replies, err := i.db.Query("SELECT * FROM latest_threads where thread_id="+threadID);
```

Comment: You could just pass in threadID as well as the slice of posts, then you can just reference it.  No need to range over anything to create the form.

Comment: How do I pass 2 things to a template? @CoryLaNou

Comment: If you share with me how you are passing the slice to the template I'll modify that code to show you how to do it.

Comment: To expand on @jimt's comment RE: SQL injection - use parameterised queries. The sqlx package (https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx) and the go-database-sql site (http://go-database-sql.org/) both have examples on how to do this depending on your DB driver (mySQL/Postgres/etc.).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass it all as one struct like so:

```
layoutData := struct {
    ThreadID int
    Posts []Post
} {
    ThreadID: threadID,
    Posts: Posts,
}
```

Then something like this will work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Test </title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h2>Reply</h2>
        <form action="/post/{{ .ThreadID }}" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="subject" />
        <input type="text" name="name" value="Anonymous" />
        <input type="text" name="message" />
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <div>
        {{range $post := .Posts}}
        <h3>{{ $post.Subject}}</h3>
        <h3>{{$post.Name}}</h3>
        <div>{{$post.DatePosted}}</div>
        <div><p>{{$post.Text}}</p></div>
        <br /><br />
        {{end}}
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! Thank you.

Comment: I'm having some issue with the range, I get this error
    unexpected <range> in range
exit status 1

EDIT: fixed it with {{range $post := .Posts}}

Comment: yup, sorry about that, I fixed the example as well.

Comment: I had the same problem, but also I want to access .ThreadID inside .Posts range scope. I don't know how can I do it.

Answer (score 5):

If the Thread Id can only be retrieved from the Post type itself, consider turning your slice of posts into a separate type. Give it a ThreadID method, which simply returns the id for the first post it contains, or zero if none exist.

```
type PostList []*Post

func (p PostList) ThreadId() int {
    if len(p) == 0 {
        return 0
    }
    return p[0].ThreadId
}
```

Pass this list into the template. Now you can reference it from the template, anywhere outside of the `{{range .}}` clause.

```
<form action="/post/{{.ThreadID}}" method="POST">
```

#### Exploit warning

As a side note, [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/) has an issue with the SQL query.
It's possible you are just posting it as a quick example. If not, be advised that your code is a recipe for [SQL injection exploits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). If the thread ID is numeric, then ensure you parse it as such, before passing it into the SQL query. E.g.: Sanitize your inputs.

Comment: props on the sqli - because i know people with copy/paste this and think their problem is solved.