# How do I parse variables outside the range in Go templates?

Tags: templates, go

I have two structs as below and I need to render the data on a template using the [templates](http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) pack. I get this error

`<.Email>: Email is not a field of struct type Notes`.

The issue seems to be that only fields of the range struct seem to be available within the range loop so I'm wondering how I can import fields from outside the range struct (e.g. the Email string).

The behavior is quite unexpected.

```
type notes struct{
    Note string
    sf string
}

type uis struct{
    notes []Note
    Email string
}

var ui uis
```

*HTML*

```
{{range .notes}}
    {{.Email}} {{.sf}}
    {{end}}

Email {{.Email}}
```

I've checked the godocs but they seem quite useless.

Comment: Maybe there are some ideas in http://stackoverflow.com/q/22366725/6309?

Comment: not really in the example provided there is no external value within the loop http://stackoverflow.com/a/22367435/3780579 . ThreadID is outside so doesn't help my case

Answer (score 38, accepted):

From the documentation:

> When execution begins, $ is set to the data argument passed to Execute, that is, to the starting value of dot.

Therefore, you can use this:

```
{{range .notes}}
    {{$.Email}} {{.sf}}
{{end}}

Email {{.Email}}
```

(Note the dollar sign inside the range)

Playground link: http://play.golang.org/p/XiQFcGJEyR

Side note: Next time try to provide proper code and a better explanation. As it stands, I *think* I've answered this, but I cannot be sure. Your code doesn't compile - for example, type names are wrong/mixed with members and you have unexported fields so they cannot be accessed by the templates.

Comment: It answers the question but the documentation still doesn't make sense to me.(i.e. How $ is set  and why the variable is not available within the range by default using a dot).

Comment: The dot is context-aware. Within the `range`, the dot refers to the current item of the iterated collection. The documentation states as such and your error says exactly that. `Email is not a field of struct type Notes` - you're iterating over a `[]Notes` slice.

Comment: Thank you so much, <select class="input form-control" name="genre" id="category">
                            <option value="">-- Thể Loại --</option>
                            {{range .categories}}
                            <option {{ .CheckSelected $.cId }} value="{{.GetLink}}">{{.Name}}</option>
                            {{end}}
                        </select>